# Java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError in eclipse

Tags: java, prism, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have made a plugin and i am trying to print an output of a batch file on a console !

The output shows this error.

**java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files (x86)\prism-4.0\lib\prism.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform**

I am new to eclipse ! Please let me know how to fix this error.

Moreover ! I want to add some manual property (user defined) in my project ! Like when we select the project and right click then **"properties"** then there are options like **"Resources", "Builders", "Task Repository", "Validation", "WikiText"** etc. etc.. ! I want to add my property say **"ABC"**. Then how can i add so? Please let me know ! It would be very helpful if i get an answer as soon as possible

I inquired once thay said that i need to know about IProjectNature. Please let me know abt more specific thing.. because i don't found it suitable in my case..

My code is...

```
    try {
        ProcessBuilder pb=new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\prism-4.0\\bin\\prism.bat");
        pb.directory(new File("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\prism-4.0\\bin"));
        Process p=pb.start();

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String in;
        while((in = input.readLine()) != null) {
            out.println(in);
        }


        int exitVal=p.waitFor();            

       out.println("Exited with error code "+exitVal+" shown and action performed \n");
```

Comment: @Andreas - Thank you very much for the response. The code is already mentioned above and i am simply trying to print the output of the batch file on console.
I even tried Silk subversion, but it ain't work. I would be helpful if you suggest me to try some other thing to make it run.
Thank You

Comment: @Andreas_D -Thank you very much for the previous answer. I have one more ques can you please suggest me, how to do so.. This is the link of question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842700/java-how-to-use-processbuilder-to-access-path-from-preference-page-and-run-pris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The software you're trying to run does not run on a 64bit JVM (which your project probably is configured to use).

Try to change the JRE library for your project to a 32bit one.

Comment: Or, download and install the AMD 64-bit version of Prism, instead of the IA 32-bit one.

Comment: @Daniel - Can you please suggest some views on this question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896101/java-how-to-access-file-path-from-preference-page-and-use-it-in-programming-cod